# Trying to restrict Input mask for dates jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Hi i have used this [input mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for phone numbers.Now i am trying to set that for my dates.I am trying to restrict only `1 to 12` number for months similarly 1 `to 31` numbers for day.I have tried different pieces of code but none of them worked.
My js code is below :

```
jQuery.mask.definitions['m'] = '1[0-2]|[1-9]'; //Tried also like 0[1-9]|1[012]
jQuery.mask.definitions['d'] = '[0-3]';
jQuery('.mdates .acf-input input').mask("m/dd/y999");
```